# Is it grammatically correct to say "what do you think to a walk in the park?"

Tags: grammar

Is is correct to say " what do you think to a walk in the park?" If not, what would be the correct way of writing it?

Comment: The question appears to be asking someone if they would like to go for a walk. It sounds a bit awkward, or phrased in a way that a non native speaker may phrase it. However, I do not believe it is entirely incorrect. I feel the awkwardness comes from the 'think to' . Hopefully someone can clarify on this a bit more than I can. That being said, another way of phrasing the sentence could be, "How do you feel about a walk in the park?" or "Would you like to walk through the park?" .

Comment: Yes, you don't think to a walk, but you *say* to a walk. You say yes.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of what we consider to be good, answerable questions. For example, at a minimum, it is unclear why you think it would be *incorrect* to say it; it will not be helpful to any future visitors, and it places a burden on the answerer to guess at your intended meaning. Requests for proofreading are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I think, “What to you ***say*** to a walk in the park” is perfectly idiomatic.  The “think to” seems like a mix of “say to” and “think of/about”

Comment: I'm going for a walk in the park.  What do you think? / What do you say?

Comment: @Jim 'What do you think to a walk in the park' is perfectly within the idiom of my speech, and its meaning is slightly different from 'what do you say to...'. 'Think' invites a slightly more nuanced response, one might enumerate the pros and cons of the park, the timing of the walk, while 'say' invites more of an *accept/decline* response. To me at least.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very idiomatic, especially for *spoken* English, to me (UK). However it seems from comments here and elsewhere (https://painintheenglish.com/case/4638/) that '*think **to***' is not universally accepted (and certainly not in the US).

The prepositions following 'think' listed by the OED are

> about, of, on, upon (arch.), by (rare), to (rare)

Other ways I would say the same thing -

> *(How) Do you fancy a walk in the park?*,
>
> *How about a walk in the park?*,
>
> *Shall we go for a walk in the park?*

Comment: Really? Sounds totally wrong to me (US). It should either be "what do you *say to* a walk in the park" or "what do you *think of* a walk in the park", but combining "think" with "to" just doesn't work.

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't be considered ungrammatical in the UK, Dan. But in the (closed) [duplicate on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20677/why-is-it-now-acceptable-to-say-what-do-you-think-to-that-rather-than-about-t), Vic correctly adds the caveat 'rare / [dated/archaic]'. But you really should be adding supporting evidence to what otherwise come across as opinions.